# How to run only a single Scalatest (via wildcardSuites) in Spark when including Maven profiles

Tags: maven, apache-spark, scalatest

I have the following command line to run a Spark scalatest via maven:

```
mvn  -pl mllib -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop2.7.1 
-Dscala-2.11 '-D!scala-2.10' -Dmaven.javoc.skip=true 
-DmembersOnlySuites=org.apache.spark.ml.feature.BinarizerSuite test
```

Let us break it down a bit:

> Select only the mllib module:

-pl mllib

> Set various profiles and scala settings:

```
-Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop2.7.1 -Dscala-2.11 '-D!scala-2.10' -Dmaven.javoc.skip=true
```

Note: those profiles and settings are required for getting the right compilation options for our environment. They have been verified many times for packaging.

> Choose the BinarizerSuite only:

```
-DwilcardSuites=org.apache.spark.ml.feature.BinarizerSuite test
```

The result is *close* to what I hope for - except the mllib ***java*** testcases are being run.

I have used the

```
mvn -DwildcardSuites=org.apache.spark.ml.feature.BinarizerSuite test
```

and that DOES do the right thing: only the one Suite is tested.  So it seems the maven command line parser is not being fed the expected order of options. But I have tried all the different permutations of ordering them..

Comment: Just a hint: use `-Dscala-2.11` only (remove '-D!scala-2.10'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sean Owen on the Spark mailing list provided the answer: I was missing the following setting:

```
 -Dtest=None
```

That setting turns off the Java tests.